# Creating a function after working out an example calculation

Tags: scoping

I have created this setup, it is giving me the correct answer, however I am interested in a function that does all this calculations and creates a output of mean and standard deviation. The function is has to be able to set the limit which i have named y, and run over a list.

```
In[302]:= list = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 20]

Out[302]= {4.48825, 3.31096, -5.1268, -2.11263, 2.04758, 7.41939, \
1.37117, 4.73285, -1.38028, 4.55688, 6.2333, 5.67909, 6.41423, \
0.709616, -3.75265, -3.16793, 2.10447, 0.583272, -0.370173, -8.65539}

In[303]:= pp = Range[Length[list]];

In[304]:= y = 2;

In[305]:= vt = If[(-y > list[[#]] || list[[#]] > y), yes, no] & /@ pp

Out[305]= {yes, yes, yes, yes, yes, yes, no, yes, no, yes, yes, yes, \
yes, no, yes, yes, yes, no, no, yes}

In[306]:= groups = SplitBy[vt, # == yes]

Out[306]= {{yes, yes, yes, yes, yes, yes}, {no}, {yes}, {no}, {yes, 
yes, yes, yes}, {no}, {yes, yes, yes}, {no, no}, {yes}}

In[307]:= fpt = DeleteCases[groups, no, {2}]

Out[307]= {{yes, yes, yes, yes, yes, yes}, {}, {yes}, {}, {yes, yes, 
yes, yes}, {}, {yes, yes, yes}, {}, {yes}}

In[308]:= rp = Range[Length[fpt]];

In[309]:= bob = Length[fpt[[#]]] & /@ rp;

In[310]:= countLength = DeleteCases[bob, 0];

In[311]:= N[StandardDeviation[countLength]]

Out[311]= 2.12132

In[312]:= N[Mean[countLength]]

Out[312]= 3.`
```

Comment: This is not a free coding service. You should try to build the function yourself. If you run into difficulties, then ask about the specific problem you have run into,

Comment: I understand that, I have spent all day trying to come up with a solution I have pages on pages with different ideas, but no one looks even close to be able to solve the problem. I also thought that this was a pretty simple coding for most of the people on this forum, so I guessed it would be easier to let you guys show me how to do it then to play around with my bad coding.

Comment: @m_goldberg, give the man a break. OP obviously tried some.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
g[l_List, y_] := N@{Mean@#, StandardDeviation@#} &@(Length /@ 
                                     Cases[Split[Not[-y < # < y ] & /@ l], {True..}])
```

Comment: Hi! This looks amazing, would you be able to explain what is going on in the code?

Comment: @ALEXANDER I'm sure you can figure it out yourself. Just start  trying the expressions inside out. Try `-y < # < y  & /@ l` first, then add `Not[]`, then `Split[]`,  and so on

Comment: Okey, thanks, also one more question, how long have you been programming?

Comment: @ALEXANDER For longer than I want to confess

Comment: You see, I started approximately 3 months ago, and been programming on a on/off bases and when you see my output compared to yours it makes me wonder if this is not for me. The progress is going extremely slow, and it looks like everyone here is smashing out code as it was there native language.

Comment: @ALEXANDER Your code is not bad, that was the reason because I decided to answer and disregard goldberg's comment above. Perhaps a good book can help you to progress faster http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/259#259

Comment: Great, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Gather your code as follows:

```
Module[{pp = Range[Length[list]], y = 2, vt, groups, fpt, rp, bob, countLength}, 
 vt = If[(-y > list[[#]] || list[[#]] > y), yes, no] & /@ pp; 
 groups = Split[vt]; fpt = DeleteCases[groups, no, {2}]; 
 rp = Range[Length[fpt]]; bob = Length[fpt[[#]]] & /@ rp; 
 countLength = DeleteCases[bob, 0];
 {N[StandardDeviation[countLength]], N[Mean[countLength]]}]
```

and check that it runs. The syntax is basically

```
Module[{vars}, code;eachLineSeparated;bySemicolons;Result]
```

Once you check it works, define the function

```
theFunction[y_][list_] := Module[{pp = Range[Length[list]], vt, groups, fpt, rp, bob, 
 countLength}, vt = If[(-y > list[[#]] || list[[#]] > y), yes, no] & /@ pp; 
  groups = Split[vt]; fpt = DeleteCases[groups, no, {2}]; 
  rp = Range[Length[fpt]]; bob = Length[fpt[[#]]] & /@ rp; 
  countLength = DeleteCases[bob, 0];
  {N[StandardDeviation[countLength]], N[Mean[countLength]]}]
```

Comment: Thank you Hector, smart way to gather and check the code, what I have done is extremely bad, but I have to start somewhere. I constantly experience new things that I am wondering about is there any easy way to example figure out what [y_][list_] is doing.

Comment: Quick and dirty, get the job done. 15 years later, you can produce the sleek code as shown in other posts. Then, you will begin thinking about optimizing the code, etc. Keep up the interest. As for f[x_][y_], because of the `:=` that follows, it defines a function. Almost like f[x_,y_], except that f[x] is itself a function. You might want check http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html?q=SetDelayed&lang=en.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely keep up the interest. Mathematica is an amazing tool.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this code produces the desired result:

```
ms[data_, 
  y_] := {Mean[#], N@StandardDeviation[#]} &@(Length /@ 
    Select[SplitBy[Boole[Abs[#] > y] & /@ data, 1], MemberQ[#, 1] &])
```

Using:

```
data = {4.48825, 3.31096, -5.1268, -2.11263, 2.04758, 7.41939, 
  1.37117, 4.73285, -1.38028, 4.55688, 6.2333, 5.67909, 6.41423, 
  0.709616, -3.75265, -3.16793, 2.10447, 0.583272, -0.370173, -8.65539}
```

`ms[data,2]` yields:

```
{3, 2.12132}
```